# Getting undefined offset error when array is defined at that index

Tags: php, arrays

each line of The file $wordFile [which is over hundreds of lines],consists of a word + 'space' + decimal number + '\n'.

I need to extract the number and word from the file and add them to the $indivFreq array. But am getting error

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /.....

This is my code:

```
    $wordFile = file_get_contents("wordFile.txt");
    $termArr = explode("\n", $wordFile);
    $wordFile2 = file_get_contents("wordFile2.txt");
    $termArr2 = explode("\n", $wordFile2);
    $cityFreqsArr = array($termArr, $termArr2);
    $twoTerms = array();
    $decimalScore = number_format("0", 8);
    $indivFreqs = array("", $decimalScore);
    $twoDimFreqArr = [[]];
    for($i=0; $i<count($termArr); $i++){

        for($i2=0; $i2 < count($cityFreqsArr[$i]); $i2++){
            $currentTerm = $cityFreqsArr[$i][$i2];
            $currentTerm = trim($cityFreqsArr[$i][$i2]);    
            $twoTerms = explode(' ', $currentTerm);    //separating each string of term and its frequency into the 2 parts

            $indivFreqs[0] = $twoTerms[0];
            $indivFreqs[1] = $twoTerms[1]; //**error is here
            $twoDimFreqArr[$i][$i2] = $indivFreqs; //for each city and each term there is an array with the term and its frequency
                                                   //i.e., 
        }
    }
```

I tried printing out the contents of $twoTerms after the explode and am getting arrays with index 0 => word and index 1 => number, Which is why I don't understand why php won't see that it has an index of 1 also?

Comment: Are you sure `$termArr` is 2-dimensional ?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to reduce the code when copying it over and omitted the 2d array I created to store two word files. See edit.

Comment: I can print $twoTerm[1], but can't assign it to anything. Any ideas? It seems very strange

Comment: Could you provide a small piece for one of files?

Comment: @BehradKhodayar:

reputations 0.00016854
thaïs 0.00016854
overflowing 0.00016854

And continues on like that (there should be line breaks after every number but comment won't allow that

Comment: debug with this: `if(count($twoTerms) == 1) var_dump($currentTerm);die();` and see what's wrong.

Comment: I put that in right after the explode and I get a blank screen as a result, so that means explode is giving $twoTerms back just one item?

Comment: gotcha. Added the answer .

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `$cityFreqsArr` as a 2-dimensional array with number of rows equal to files being read(which for this particular example is 2. first row(with `$index=0`) is holding `$wordFile.txt`/`$termArr`'s data. And second row for the second one.

Now for storing data for each city, each term & their respective term & frequency you should first traverse `$cityFreqsArr` by its rows (as files) & then second level `$index` (as content of each file). So, I updated first & second `for`'s conditions regarding this.

```
$wordFile = file_get_contents("wordFile.txt");
$termArr = explode("\n", $wordFile);
$wordFile2 = file_get_contents("wordFile2.txt");
$termArr2 = explode("\n", $wordFile2);
$cityFreqsArr = array($termArr, $termArr2);
$twoTerms = array();
$decimalScore = number_format("0", 8);
$indivFreqs = array("", $decimalScore);
$twoDimFreqArr = [[]];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($cityFreqsArr); $i++) { //Traversing file by file
  for ($i2 = 0; $i2 < count($cityFreqsArr[$i]); $i2++) { //Traversing in each file
    $twoTerms = explode(' ', trim($cityFreqsArr[$i][$i2]));
    $indivFreqs[] = $twoTerms[0];
    $indivFreqs[] = $twoTerms[1];
    $twoDimFreqArr[$i][$i2] = $indivFreqs;
  }
}

// Test it:
echo '<pre>';
print_r($twoDimFreqArr);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: @AndrewY  Does this answer solve your issue?  If so, please award it the green tick; if not, please offer feedback to NDFA in the form of a comment so the answer can be edited.  Only resolved questions benefit future SO readers/researchers.